# react-router some routes not matching

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have private routes

*app-routes.js* file

```
const routes = [
{ path: '/', component: HomePage },
{ path: '/articles/:id', component: Article },
{ path: '/expert', component: Experts },
...
{ path: '/requests', component: ComRequest },
{ path: '/admin', component: AdminHomePage },]

export default routes.map(route => {
 return {
  ...route,
  component: route.component
 }
})
```

*content.js* file iterates app-routes as array
if not match any routes redirects to **/**

```
import routes from 'app-routes'

return(
 <Switch>
  {routes.map(({ path, component }) => (
    <PrivateRoute
     exact
     key={path}
     path={path}
     component={component}
    />
   ))}
  <Redirect to={'/'} />
 </Switch>)
```

*PrivateRoute.js*
component file checks user if not redirect to **/login**

```
function PrivateRoute({ component, ...rest }) {
 return (
  <Switch>
   <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(matchProps) => getUser()
     ?
      <WithLayout
       {...matchProps}
       component={component}
       layout={MainLayout}
      />
      :
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: matchProps.location } }} />}
   />
  </Switch>
 )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

**getUser()** function returns Object string {userdata}

*getUser.js*

```
export function getUser() {
 return localStorage.getItem('user')
}
```

in browser some **/articles**, **/expert** routes renders view but  random or logic couldn't figure out how routes other some **/requests**, **/admin** routes not matching and redirects to **/**

some times every routes redirect to **/**

if I comment `<Redirect to={'/'}/>` some routes renders white screen

**and one more annoying thing is**
on refresh always redirect works goes to **/** url not staying on matched routes

in `app.js` checks user if found returns `Content` if not user returns `NotAuthenticatedContent` routes

```
const { user } = useAuth()
if (user && user.id) {
  return <Content />
 } else
  return <NotAuthenticatedContent />
};
```

`user` imports from AuthContext

```
function AuthProvider(props) {
 const [user, setUser] = useState()
 const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.account)
 useEffect(() => {
  (async function () {
   if (currentUser && currentUser.jwt)
     setUser(currentUser.user)
   })();
 }, []);
 return (<AuthContext.Provider value={{user}} {...props}/>)
}
const AuthContext = createContext({})
const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)
export {AuthProvider,useAuth}
```

I noticed `history.push('/requests')` can go to /requests page
but when I type in url section redirects to /

Comment: What are "top routes" and "bottom routes"? Can you clarify and provide examples of what works and what doesn't? What is `getUser`? Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Seems we still need a lot of context, or a reproducible example. I copy/pasted your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-some-routes-not-matching-4u4yy) and I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Also, why did you mark this bounty as wanting an up-to-date answer when there aren't any outdated answers, or any answers at all? Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? Can you try also creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: your use of `key=` is odd. start by just exporting routes array without mapping, `export default routes`, and tell us the result.

Comment: what version of React are you using? newest v6 has some backward incompatible changes.

Comment: Make sure that you are using `BrowserRouter` as parent of switch and only in one place. And what the reason to use switches in switch, please remove `Switch` from `PrivateRoute` and try again. P.S. Another reason of issue can be the the version of `react-router-dom` as usage of the package has changed for higher versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put ***console.log()*** every where and figured it out
it was `app.js`

```
const { user } = useAuth()
if (user && user.id) {
 console.log('user logged in')
 return <Content />
} else
 console.log('user not logged in')
 return <NotAuthenticatedContent/>
}
```

in browser `user`'s first value or initial was null and in console ***user not logged in*** printed and later that ***user logged in*** was also printed so `user` checking is was wrong then `<NotAuthenticatedContent/>` was returned which had some same routes such as `/articles/:id,/expert`

Answer (score 1):

Working with web-based technology, you need to get used to using browser developer tools. there you will see many errors regarding your empty pages.

these errors are mostly due to major version changes in react, react-router, react-router-dom, and partly how you try to install them with npm.

to solve your problem, first, make sure you have the 5th versions of these tools. trying to install without a version will result in the latest versions installed. switch to v6 when you are confident with your app's functioning but be ready for lots of changes.

```
npx create-react-app@5 appName
npm install react-router@5
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

if versions do not match well, you will get errors for incompatible imports on the console, but many of the errors are runtime only on the browser, so open developer tools to see what else is going wrong.

I have tried your code fragments. they don't have a problem except for these version incompatibilities and some logic errors.

- you don't need to export a new object from mapped from your routes unless you really change the structure, so `export default routes` is enough.
- you dont have a direct route to login page. in the switch component of `content.js` and outside your private route mapping, add `<Route exact key="/login" path="/login" render={Login}/>`
- other than these, make sure your routes do not shadow some partial matches

I have uploaded my sample app on github: [react-v5-simple-login-route-layout](https://github.com/yilmazdurmaz/react-v5-simple-login-route-layout). for this, I used above commands, deleted everything in source folder except `index.*` and `App.js`, copied OP's code fragments as is, edited only the parts parts I mentioned above, added missing page components and login/logout pages to clear localstorage, and improvised layout.

Comment: Is it not obvious by use of `Switch` and `Route` use with `component` and `render` props OP is using RRDv5? If they accidentally installed v6 then there'd be many more errors and none of the routes would work. I suspect OP's issue is more to do with some asynchronous nature of authentication with the described sometimes works sometimes doesn't auth redirection.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks for the notes. OP does not tell anything about how they set up their project.  just using a `create-react-app` does not give you the correct versions for other packages. that way, there come many errors but only the in-browser dev tool shows and I strongly suspect OP ignored. I did the above steps and have seen few possible outcomes until I hit the correct setup, then made the working app in the link. the the logic part comes in to give blank page because of errors and `/` problem.

Comment: I only cant replicate "sometimes works" statement with the info OP gave, and it is most possibly just for shadowing routes hence my warning.

Comment: I've been completely unable to reproduce any issue OP describes. See my comments and codesandbox dating back a week or so. Your answer is essentially more of the same. Op hasn't responded nor updated their question either. Unfortunately they added a bounty so close votes can't be cast, so I've been waiting this one out.

Comment: @DrewReese, I see your concern and the problem you faced. you haven't given a full answer because you couldn't replicate the issue. the problem I see is that you used codesandbox's templates that seems to come with correct versions and also you possibly wrote yours to a perfection that you missed the problems I could catch. I have worked with nodejs by adding needed packages only when I see an error.

Comment: No, I copy/pasted OP's code and specified the v5 version (as this post was originally tagged) and only omitted the invalid text stuff like "..." and "...route" that would break compiling. The code ran without issue basically from the get go without much "tweaking" on my part. I was only pointing out to you that OP is using v5 and so I don't think there's an issue with anything v6 related as if that was the case then the code wouldn't run period.

Comment: @DrewReese going from scratch with nodejs, my first attempt resulted with v6 app, thus `create-react-app@5` is needed. then adding packages by npm install gave me v6 packages, thus `react-router@v5` and `react-router-dom@v5`. this is the workflow for most coders: add when required. and sometimes results in these weird problems.

Comment: Ok, and codesandbox is much different? It's just an online web IDE. ‍♂️ Anyway... we've gotten a little off-topic here. Will wait 1 more day to see if OP updates with new and relevant details. Cheers.

Comment: codesandbox uses their own templates for frameworks while nodejs uses barebones templates provided by the frameworks. if you have nodejs installed give it a try and you will immediately see the difference. I don't expect OP to show up for another week let alone award his bounty. answers not voted on by others or accepted by OP are not awarded bounty. I just saw it has no answers and also found it interesting and tried to see if I could replicate, then shared the experience.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. The CSB base React template uses `create-react-app` and `react-scripts`, same as if you used node from CLI to create a new React project... it is just really convenient for standing up quick POCs right in the browser. Other than the base `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts` packages a new React sandbox is pretty empty and it's up to you to fill in the rest.